# RewriteCond www and non www to subpage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

I'm a newbie and the question is simple, I want mysite.eu and www.mysite.eu redirect to a subpage of their website,
but I can't get it to work for both because when I add something like this I got stuck in a loop so how can I fix this that both wil direct to that subpage without getting a loop.

My example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  www\.mysite\.eu [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.mysite.eu/page?page=webshop_fixol&lng=1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  mysite\.eu [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.mysite.eu/page?page=webshop_fixol&lng=1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a single rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(www\.)?mysite\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule . page?page=webshop_fixol&lng=1 [L,QSA]
```

`^(www\.)?mysite\.eu$` will match both sites `www` and non `www`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but I've tested it and I get an infinite loop for mysite.eu and www.mysite.eu, could the reason of this be that I have this also in the code the headers:Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews or this also in the virtualhost file: RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^/(.+[^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [R]

Comment: He adds: http://fixol.eu/page?page=webshop_fixol&lng=1&page=webshop_fixol&lng=1&page=webshop_fixol... in the url

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have the . there? sure you did not just want this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  www\.mysite\.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.mysite.eu/page?page=webshop_fixol&lng=1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  mysite\.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.mysite.eu/page?page=webshop_fixol&lng=1 [R=permanent,L]
```